# Single statement in method implementation is taking up 90% of the run time. Causes the app to receive memory warnings and crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments, cgpoint, memory-pressure

I have a photo taking app that uses AVFoundation. When the user presses the button to capture a photo, a lot of things happen like rotating the photo to the correct orientation, cropping, etc.

I have been getting "received memory warning" messages in the console when capturing images, and after I have captured a couple images and deleted them the app will crash 99% of the time.

I just went and ran the app with Instruments and there is one method in the Call Tree that takes up 53.6% of the run time. I double clicked on this method and was shown the percentage of time spent on each statement in this method's implementation, and there is one single statement that takes up 90.5% of the time.

Obviously, this is what is causing my memory issues and app crashes, but I'm not exactly sure why or how to fix it.

Here is the method implementation code:

```
-(UIImage*) rotate:(UIImage*) src andOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation

{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context=(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

      if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI) ;
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90/180*M_PI);
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI);
        }


    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];



    UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;

}
```

The statement that is taking up 90.5% of the time is:

```
[src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Basically, the point of this method implementation, is to rotate the captured photo to the proper orientation, since iOS by default will store the image as landscape even though it was just captured in portrait. So you have to rotate back to portrait to get it just like it was captured.

I am not sure why the single statement above is causing problems, but I really need to fix it so I can increase the performance of my app and stop these crashes from happening.

Comment: You know that you can change the orientation of the capture output, right? If memory serves me right, it should be a property on the capture connection.

Comment: if it's a large image, drawing it using this API will be slow. also, what happens to the `img` you return? are you sure it's released later? A better way to draw your image rotated/scaled is to put it in a CALayer and set it's `transform` property to a rotation transform.

Comment: @David I was under the impression that for whatever reason, iOS will always rotate the image 90 degrees so if you really want to edit the portrait captured photo you have to rotate it before you work with it.

Comment: Try to think about presenting the image transformed, rather than transforming the image's data. That will be more efficient.

Comment: The image will contain orientation information I believe.

Comment: If that doesn't work the I believe that it will be much more efficient to rotate the image using ImageIO

Comment: @nielsbot Yes, it should be part of the metadata.

Comment: Ok, I think the first thing you should do it check out `UIImageView` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I just went and made sure I had access to set it, and then I am changing the capture connection's videoOrientation property. The value changes in the console but it still is not making any difference.

Comment: @nielsbot When I NSLog the image's imageOrientation property the value is 2.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html